# WordPress hijacked - all subdomains effected

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

Just have a question :)

I have a WordPress site with domainname "site.com". It is on its own server.
On another server I have an admin site located on the subdomain "admin.site.com", and a booking site on "booking.site.com" - they are not i WordPress.

Now my WordPress site gets hijacked, and all browser shows a warning, and I'm removed from Google. But it is not only site.com which is closed, but all my subdomains. Why? And is there a way to separate, so the subdomains not will be close if my WordPress site gets hijacked again?

Answer (score 0):

By close, do you mean removed from Google or non-functional in general?

Google doesn't have a lot of forgiveness when it comes to site issues, so afaik it will block the subdomains if the main domain gets compromised.
If your other sites aren't functional, you might want to check your site.com's htaccess file.